# How to implement function which picks node of a tree randomly using reservoir sampling in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I need to write a function that will pick one node of a tree randomly with probability 1/n , where n is number of all nodes in C , using reservoir sampling or any other clever and efficient way .

I don't know the number of nodes .

How to do this ?

Comment: Unless your data has some special structure that can be exploited, you already gave the answer. Use reservoir sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Walk the tree recursively. Store (references to) all nodes in a flat list.

After returning from the walk you pick one item form the list (which's length is now known)